# Dentists are very safe

Tags: idioms

> "You will keep looking [through books for Mr. Flamel] while I'm away [on holidays], won't you?" said Hermione. "And send me an owl if you find anything."
>
> And you could ask your parents if they know who Flamel is," said Ron. "**It'd be safe to ask them**."
> (Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone)

Hermione replies to Ron, "**Very safe, as they're both dentists**":
I guess Hermione’s parents can keep secrets about Magic world for they wear masks and their clients have to open wide during services. But is there any British tale or idiom about the keeping secret of dentists?

Comment: I think Hermione is being ironic--she is tartly reminiding Ron that her parents are Muggles and follow a Muggle profession, so it is very unlikely that they would have any idea what she was talking about.

Comment: @StoneyB, Yes, I got it. So magicians make sight of Muggle’s medical practice. This kind of thoughts are not rare in our country, for they rely more on traditional healing mechanism that see a human as a human not a body that could be cut up. And so I myself prefer to go traditional medical clinic than western styles. Modern sciences are getting nearer to non-Muggle world, I think. [wikia](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Doctor)

Comment: In the Potterverse there are no doubt magical practitioners who command spells for repairing living teeth! :)

Comment: I don't think it really has anything to do with her parents being *specifically* dentists (or of any medical profession). She could have said "Very safe, as they're both kindergarten teachers" and the effect would be exactly the same. As @StoneyB said, the point is to emphasize that they're non-magical, not that they have a medical profession. "They won't have any idea who he is, they have zero connection to magic." That's the point. :)

Comment: @WendiKidd perzackly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it really has anything to do with her parents being specifically dentists (or of any medical profession). She could have said "Very safe, as they're both kindergarten teachers" and the effect would be exactly the same. As @StoneyB said, the point is to emphasize that they're non-magical, not that they have a medical profession. "They won't have any idea who he is, they have zero connection to magic." That's the point.